# How to block/ban clients that try to access some paths / urls?

Tags: apache-2.2, iptables, firewall, mod-security, csf

Some spambots hammer my server with nonexisting paths like /user/pass?=asdfdasfas
How could I block any access to /user/pass?=* ?

Is there a better tool than iptables or csf for catching such crap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)

It automatically blocks the IP of the spambot or malicious user for a user defined period of time once it detects a user defined number of requests to non-existent pages, failed login attempts etc. We currently use it to protect against ssh attacks but are now extending it to our website.

Comment: ... and txt2re.com is your new friend